# Codemod vs. eslint --fix

Tags: eslint, codemod

I want to write a couple of scripts to automatically detect missing imports and import them based upon a root directory.  Is it better to write this script as a codemod script or as an eslint rule with the fix option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codemods are meant for migrations while linting is there permanently to nag/warn your developers about some mistake they have potentially made while developing. Both can be used together.

For your case, I think there are two approaches you can take:

1. Write a lint rule that detects the problem and a codemod to fix existing occurences of the problem. The lint rule ensures that developers won't miss that out in future.
2. Write a lint rule that detects the problem along with a [`--fix`](https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-rules-new#applying-fixes) option to automatically fix the problem.

I would lean towards approach two because it's more futureproof. You might want to just use this [`no-unresolved` ESLint rule](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-unresolved.md) directly rather than writing your own. In any case, the fix/codemod is not trivial and can be a performance hit if your project has many directories and files.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine both worlds and use [**Putout**](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout) code transformer I’m working on for a couple years. It can be used as a [plugin for ESLint](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout/tree/v25.6.0/packages/eslint-plugin-putout) and very useful for writing `codemods`, because it has all needed infrastructure:

- ✅ [test runner](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout/tree/v25.6.0/packages/test);
- ✅ declarative [API](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout/tree/v25.6.0/packages/engine-runner) based on templates;
- ✅ [handbook](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/plugin-handbook.md) to learn from;
- ✅ [an editor](https://putout.cloudcmd.io);

With help of [scopes](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/plugin-handbook.md#scopes) you can easily detect is variable that you use is declared or not.

Here is example of a `plugin` which does what you need: [@putout/plugin-declare-undefined-variables](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout/tree/v18.14.0/packages/plugin-declare-undefined-variables) it works this way:

```js
import {template} from 'putout';

export const match = () => ({
    'await readFile(__a, __b)': (vars, path) => {
        return !path.scope.bindings.readFile;
    }
});

export const replace = () => ({
    'await readFile(__a, __b)': (vars, path) => {
        const programScope = path.scope.getProgramParent();
        const importNode = template.ast('import {readFile} from "fs/promises"');
        programScope.path.node.body.unshift(importNode);
        return path;
    }
});
```

Here is how it looks like in **Putout Editor**:

[image: Putout Editor]

Comment: Please don't forget to [disclose your affiliation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) with the library

Comment: ✅ Disclosed affiliation.